# Issue Installing Stable-Diffusion on macOS due to 'torch_directml'

Tags: python, macos, torch, stable-diffusion

I've been trying to install Stable-Diffusion on my MacBook Pro, but I encountered an error related to torch_directml. As I understand, torch_directml is specific to Windows and DirectX environments. Could you please advise on how to proceed with the installation on macOS?

Here are the specifications of my MacBook Pro for reference:

- Model: MacBook Pro 16-inch, 2019
- Processor: 2.3 GHz 8-Core Intel Core i9
- Graphics: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M 4 GB and Intel UHD Graphics 630 1536 MB
- Memory: 16 GB 2667 MHz DDR4
- macOS : Sonoma 14.0

Here is the error message I received:

```
################################################################
Install script for stable-diffusion + Web UI
Tested on Debian 11 (Bullseye)
################################################################

################################################################
Running on user
################################################################

################################################################
Repo already cloned, using it as install directory
################################################################

################################################################
Create and activate python venv
################################################################

################################################################
Launching launch.py...
################################################################
fatal: No names found, cannot describe anything.
Python 3.10.9 (main, Mar  1 2023, 12:33:47) [Clang 14.0.6 ]
Version: 1.6.0
Commit hash: 44f1acaae3ef6868a4767eb3c89b8265664aada5
Launching Web UI with arguments: --skip-torch-cuda-test --upcast-sampling --no-half-vae --use-cpu interrogate
2023-10-05 19:42:39.837650: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:182] This TensorFlow binary is optimized to use available CPU instructions in performance-critical operations.
To enable the following instructions: AVX2 FMA, in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
no module 'xformers'. Processing without...
no module 'xformers'. Processing without...
No module 'xformers'. Proceeding without it.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/stable-diffusion-webui/launch.py", line 48, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/stable-diffusion-webui/launch.py", line 44, in main
    start()
  File "/Users/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/launch_utils.py", line 679, in start
    import webui
  File "/Users/stable-diffusion-webui/webui.py", line 13, in <module>
    initialize.imports()
  File "/Users/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/initialize.py", line 34, in imports
    shared_init.initialize()
  File "/Users/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/shared_init.py", line 25, in initialize
    dml.initialize()
  File "/Users/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/dml/__init__.py", line 40, in initialize
    from modules.dml.backend import DirectML # pylint: disable=ungrouped-imports
  File "/Users/stable-diffusion-webui/modules/dml/backend.py", line 4, in <module>
    import torch_directml # pylint: disable=import-error
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch_directml'
```

Any guidance or workaround would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After several attempts. I finally able to install it.

**Solution for Installing stable-diffusion-webui with 'torch_directml' error.**

1. **Create and Activate a Virtual Environment:**

   `python3 -m venv stable_diffusion_env`

   `source stable_diffusion_env/bin/activate`
2. **Clone the Repository:**

   `git clone https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/stable-diffusion-webui.git`
3. **Navigate to the Repository:**

   `cd stable-diffusion-webui`
4. **Install Specific Torch and Torchvision Versions:**

   `pip install torch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2`
5. **Upgrade pip:**

   `pip install --upgrade pip`
6. **Customize 'webui-user.sh'**

   `if [[ -x "$(command -v python3.10)" ]]`

   `then`

   `python_cmd="python3.10"`

   `fi`

   `export install_dir="$HOME"`

   `export COMMANDLINE_ARGS="--skip-torch-cuda-test --upcast-sampling --no-half-vae --use-cpu interrogate"`

   `export TORCH_COMMAND="pip install torch==2.0.1 torchvision==0.15.2"`

   `export PYTORCH_ENABLE_MPS_FALLBACK=1`
7. **Run the 'webui.sh' script.**

   `./webui.sh`